# Image change from dropdown using AJAX

Tags: php, html, css, navigation

Here I have one drop down menu on which selection other dropdown changes result the id of other dropdown is "style_code". Now I also want to change image on  dropdown selection, it is like when I select color from dropdown it changes sizes which is other dropdown, but I also want to change image on color selection.

```
<script>
    function getState(val) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check.php",
            data:'id='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#style_code").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is check.php

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db") or die(mysql_error());

if(!empty($_POST["id"])) {
    $query ="SELECT * FROM stylecolor WHERE color_code = '" . $_POST["id"] . "'";
    $results = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while ( ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results))){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row["color_name"]; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['size'] ; ?>
        </option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should add dataType: "json," to your ajax and then return the data in the check.php file as "return json_encode($data); " You simply cannot show the option values in the check.php page unless you are posting it to the same page without using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your difficulty comes from the fact that you are returning HTML code from the PHP script. My advice is to return JSON data then generate **style_code** children with jQuery.

It would be something like that :

**check.php**

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db") or die(mysql_error());

if(!empty($_POST["id"])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM stylecolor WHERE color_code = '" . $_POST["id"] . "'";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $data = new stdClass(); // This object will carry the results

    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results))) {
        $data->option[] = $row;
    }

    // Another query to get the image name
    $query = "SELECT name FROM image_name WHERE color_code = '" . $_POST["id"] . "'";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results)) {
        $data->image_name = $row->name;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

**HTML & Javascript:**

```
...

<div class="thumb-image" id="style_image" >
    <img src="images/<?php echo $productimg1?>" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
</div>

...

<script language="javascript">
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check.php",
        data: {id: val},
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#style_code").children().remove(); // empty the dropdown
            // Add new options in the dropdown from the result data
            data.option.forEach(function (item) {
                $("#style_code").append('<option value="' + item.color_name + '">' + item.size + '</option>');
            });
            // Change the 'src' attribute of the <img>
            $("#style_image").find('img').attr('src', 'images/' + data.image_name + '?d=' + Date.now().toString());
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: also add unix time to new image src. -> $("#style_image").attr('src', data.image_url+'?v='+ unix time here);

Comment: Otherwise the image will not change on client side

Comment: thanks , i have a table name image_name (which store just names and get the image from folder) in the same table style color how will i append it with this ,,, <div class="thumb-image" id="style_image" > <img src="images/<?php echo $productimg1?>" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" alt="" /> </div>

Comment: I edited the post to take your comments in account. Thanks @CavidKərimov